# Why the need for specific app info in order to get a license?

Tags: chaquopy

Is the license actually per app? E.g. get a separate license for every app I make using Chaquopy?

I have no specific apps in mind, yet would be interested in a license... Is this possible somehow? 5 minutes aren't enough to try everything...

I mean, why not do it like Qt, they don't need any info... Talking about personal dogfooding stuff here, if I ever put something in public, it would be open-source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open-source apps are licensed individually. Once you start using Chaquopy with a specific app, just publish its source code on a public site like GitHub, even if it's in an early stage of development, and then we'll be happy to give you a license for free.

For non-open-source apps, you can choose between an unlimited-app license or a cheaper single-app license. Prices are listed [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/paid-license/).